# Storing Avro files in HDFS

Tags: python, hdfs, avro, bigdata

I am trying to store lot of data on HDFS. I have been able to generate Avro files using Python. Does Avro provides the functionality of storing the output directly to HDFS?

Comment: Read the ü manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avro is serialization framework intended to store data in avro format, it doesn't have the intelligence to write anything to HDFS.

You need to use HDFS api to upload/write your avros to HDFS, use something similar in python
, where srcPath is the local avro and dstPath is on HDFS

```
public void uploadToHdfs(String srcPath, String dstPath) throws IOException {
        FileSystem fs = getFileSystem();
        fs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path(srcPath), new Path(dstPath));
}
```

Thanks